# Array of objects isn't empty but *ngFor shows as if there are none

Tags: javascript, angular

I use an HTTP Get request to get a list of notifications, the name could be misinterpreted because it is just a list of posts that is collected, it doesn't change. The problem is that I use an array to collect all the notifications with an interface and it doesn't display them.

If I use a button called test to check the content of the array I see that all the objects are in the array yet it doesn't work. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2ITT.png)

The example under load more is an example of one notification and how it should look like (hardcoded)
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmde7.png)

**Code overview.component.html**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Notifications
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush small">
          <app-notification *ngFor="let notification1 of notifications" icon1="{{notification1.icon}}" message1="{{notification1.message}}"></app-notification>

          <button mat-raised-button (click)="test()">test</button>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Load more...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p *ngFor="let notif of notifications">{{notif.id}}</p>
```

**Code overview.component.ts**

```
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  notifications : Notificatie[] = [];

  constructor(private NotificationService: NotificationServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.NotificationService.getNotifications().subscribe((reponse => {this.notifications = Object.values(reponse)}));
  }
  test(){
    console.log(this.notifications);
  }

}
```

**Code Notificatie Interface**

```
export interface Notificatie {
    id?:number;
    message:string;
    icon:string;
}
```

**Code Notification Service**

```
export class NotificationServiceService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5be453402f00002c00d9f48f";
  

  // Observable<Notificatie[]>
  getNotifications(): Observable<Notificatie[]>{
    return this.http.get<Notificatie[]>(this.url)
    
  }
}
```

Code notification.component.ts

```
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message1:string|undefined;
  @Input() icon1: string |undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.message = this.message1;
    this.icon = this.icon1;
  }
  message:string | undefined;
  icon: string | undefined;
  date = new Date()

}
```

Code notification.component.html

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <div class="media">
        <i class="{{icon}}"></i>
        <div class="media-body">
            <p>{{message}}</p>
            <div class="text-muted smaller">{{date}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

**UPDATE still not showing on the site**

I fixed it by adding | async but the site doesn't display any of the notifications.

```
<app-notification *ngFor="let notification1 of notifications$ |async" [icon1]="notification1.icon" [message1]="notification1.message"></app-notification>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use manual changeDetection or async pipe

```
constructor(
  private NotificationService: NotificationServiceService,
  private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
) { }

this.NotificationService.getNotifications().subscribe((response => {
  this.notifications = Object.values(response);
  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}));
```

More preferred way

```
notifications$: Observable<Notificatie[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.notifications$ = this.NotificationService.getNotifications();
}

<app-notification
  *ngFor="let notification1 of notifications$ | async"
  [icon1]="notification1.icon"
  [message1]="notification1.message"
></app-notification>
```

Comment: I tried to implement the second solution you gave but at the init it gives `Type 'Observable<Notificatie[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Notificatie>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more.` error

Comment: forgot mapping.
 `this.notifications$ = this.NotificationService.getNotifications().pipe(
   map((response) => Object.values(response),
 );`

Comment: I tried doing that, the problems are solved in the .ts files but now it errors in the html file. I added an update with an image to the post.